# AJAX response for file download is in encoded format.

Tags: jquery, ajax, excel

I make an ajax call as

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', 'John');
formData.append('company', 'ABC');

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: formData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(data){
     window.location.href = data.URL;   // data does not have URL attribute.
  },
  error: function(err){}
});
```

Here, I should ideally get an excel file download as response.

However, the

```
success: function(data){

}
```

Here the `data` that i get contains a bunch of encoded values which I can see in the browser console. How can I get the download url here.

Comment: You've prepared your ajax options as though you want to upload a file. I think you should have regular ajax options and also include `dataType:'json'` and make sure your server is returning a `JSON`, then you can grab the `file URL` as you're trying to do. **NO NEED TO USE FormData()**.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually, I have to send the formData to the service, the service sends me the data. Inside success: function(data){}, when i do console.log(data) I can see an encoded output in the browser. But I don't have the data.URL

Comment: I see. Is it because the service is not sending it? I really don't know what you're trying to do but maybe you could take a look at the `table2CSV` jQuery plugin; it may give you an idea or two .... just a shot in the dark :)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is meant to be used for sending/retrieving data, so obviously you will get data in success function.

You should make POST with ordinary form and make sure that server is setting the right header.

```
<form method="post" action="/path/to/excel/file">
    ...
</form>
```

After form make POST, and server supply data and HEADER if your browser does not support viewing of excel files the download will start.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download files with ajax that would be saved on you hardrive for security reasons.
There is a previous question covering the same problem:
[Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I think he's just getting back by ajax just the URL  of the file, not the file itself.

Comment: But then the download url should be the same as he was specifying the ajax call AKA variable url?, or am I overlooking something, please clarify.

Comment: I think there's a confusion of variables - `data` in success not to be confused with `formData` sent to server. He's not even sending a URL to the server but expects to receive one from the server. Maybe I have it wrong but that's how it appears to me.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I send formData to the server, the server sends me the response in the success: function(data){}. However,when I do console.log(data), i can see encoded values in the browser. I cannot get any data.URL

Comment: So you requested with a URL and you get a response, what URL is this response-URL suppose to represent?